# How to skip elements in python for loop?

Tags: python

In Java/C++/etc. we can change the value of the for-loop control variable, but how can we accomplish the same in Python?

For example, let's say I have list nums[5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3], and in a for loop I want to add the current element and the one immediately after it, then skip to the third index and repeat. So list[0] + list[1], list[2] + list[3]...

In Java/C++/etc. we can do this by:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i += 2) {
 some variable = list[i] + list[i + 1];
 // whatever else
}
```

How can I accomplish the equivalent in Python?

Comment: @TimRoberts in Python it's probably `len(nums)` or `nums.size`, though.

Comment: Doh.  Too much C++ recently.

Answer (score 3):

You can use zip in conjunction with some judicious slicing like this:

```
list_ = [5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3]

for x, y in zip(list_[::2], list_[1::2]):
    print(x + y)
```

**Output:**

```
6
6
6
```

Comment: Thank you! Python is new to me so I did'nt know

Answer (score 1):

You can write it this way, setting the step of 2 in the iteration:

```
list_ = [5, 1, 2, 4, 3, 3]
for i in range(0, len(list_), 2):
    print(list_[i] + list_[i+1])
```

```
Output:
6
6
6
```

Comment: Thank you, I'm learning python so I wasn't sure how to do that

Answer (score 0):

first and second arguments in python built-in function range() declare start and stop and third argument declares step.
so you can use range and iterate your list like the code below(equivalent to your code):

```
for i in range(0, len(sample_list), 2):
   some_variable = sample_list[i] + sample_list[i+1]
   # whatever else
```